# Connection to SQL Server Database inside Visual Studio connectionString error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've import my SQL 2005 database to my project and i am trying to connect to the database using the web.config

But I've this error when I add the connectionString to the web.config.

```
    <add name="strConn" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=intranet_db;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Detailed Error Information:

- Module    IIS Web Core
- Notification    Unknown
- Handler    Not yet determined
- Error Code    0x80070032
- Config Error    The configuration section 'add' cannot be read
  because it is missing a section declaration
- Config File    \?\C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio
  2012\Projects\test\test\web.config
- Requested URL localhost:64198/
- Physical Path
- Logon Method    Not yet determined
- Logon User    Not yet determined
- Request Tracing Directory
  C:\Users\user\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\

  Am I doing it wrong? What should I add in the web.config?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us your complete web.config

Comment: Could you provide the surrounding code? I cannot see any errors in add tag itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you put the "add" tag in the correct place. I'm able to reproduce your error when I place it i wrong section. Your web.config file should look like this:

```xml
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="strConn" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=intranet_db;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be something like this

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="connectionString" connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=dbhostname;Persist Security Info=True;Password='password';User ID='username';Initial Catalog=dbname" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/ it has examples of what they should be.

looking at you connection string make sure the instance name ./SqlExpress is correct.

A quick test would be to load sql manager and connect with the ./SqlExpress

Standard Security

Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword;

Trusted Connection
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;

to give you a better answer would require knowing how you want to connect to the database.

Comment: I am trying to connect to localhost sqlexpress and I have changed my .\sqlexpress to (localdb)\v11.0 but still have the same error.

Comment: what is your instance name? if it's local and default settings it should be YourPCName/SqlExpress.